# How to Mass Add using Regex

Tags: regex

before :

```
example@email.com|password
example1@email.com|password
```

after using regex:

```
smtp.gmail.com|example@email.com|password
smtp.gmail.com|example1@email.com|password
```

what's code how to mass add a smtp.gmail.com using regex

please with demo :(

Comment: Why regex when you want to append something?

Comment: because I want to add mass

Comment: or non-re replace \r\n with \r\smtp.gmail.com| then stick another at the front

Comment: thanks .. working (Y)

Comment: why you not answer question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in general one does not need Regex for this, but if you aren't programming, and just want to use Notepad++, just use this:

Search: `^(.+)$`
Replace: `smtp.gmail.com|$1`